# upload image to media server with chopper

Tags: flutter

I try to upload photo to media server this way

```
 @Post(path: 'file')
  @Multipart()
  Future<Response<UploadPhotoResponse>> uploadPhoto(@PartFile('file') String file);
```

String file is file path from android storage.

and it uploads, but then i can't display it with CachedNetworkImage. Media server give me file without extension. So i must designate that i upload image with jpeg extension. Google say to me that i have to set filename some where. So content type of file will be image/jpeg. How i can do it ?